# Packages reference in java

Tags: java, package

I don't have so much experience in java, so i would like your help, because there is something that i can not understand in packages.

Let's we suppose that i have the following structure in my package:

com-> src->myClass.java

Where **com** is an empty directory which includes the src directory and **src** is the main directory which contains the myClass file.

Assuming that i want to create a class outside of the package which contains the main method, which is the correct reference?

I think that it is : `import com.src.myClass;`

Please find below:

```java
import com.src.myClass; 

public class ClassMain
{

    // i did not receive error to the reference of the class  
    myClass t1 = new myClass();
    or
    com.src.myClass t1 = new com.src.myClass();


    // i receive error to the call of method despite that its modifier is public
    t1.diplay();  
}
```

May i have your help please?

Thanks

Comment: What's the error message? Does `t2.display()` not produce the same error?

Comment: Using `src` here is confusing. That is the conventional abbreviation of “source code”. Unless your company is named “SRC”, I suggest you omit that word from your package naming.

Comment: I suspect your class has no such method named `diplay`. Did you misspell the method name, `diplay`, with a missing “s”?

Comment: Maybe he works for [Exponent](http://src.com/)

Comment: Add myClass code, it will help